# PHP: Getting the value of a radio button and storing it into a database

Tags: php

I have never really used radio buttons before. So what I am trying to achieve is, using two radio buttons 'Public' and 'Private'. This is for the user's profile. My HTML code for the buttons is;

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="privacy" name="privacy"   value="0">Private</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="privacy" name="privacy"   value="1">Public</button>
</div>
```

As for the PHP, I'm not sure how to get the value and store it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a form.

```
<form method="get" action="yourscript.php">

  <input type="radio" id="private" name="privacy" value="0">
  <label for="private">Private</label>

  <input type="radio" id="public" name="privacy" value="1">
  <label for="public">Public</label>

  <input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

Change your buttons to `input` elements, which, together with the form, provide a HTML native way to send data to a script without the need for Javascript (although you can use Javascript to enhance the usability later on).

Using the `label` tag, you can assign a text to a radiobutton. This allows this text to be clicked as well, and it also provides better support for screen readers, because they can actually see which text belongs to the radiobutton.

An `id` needs to be unique, so I changed it to `private` and `public`. The ids are also used to link the label to.

The `name` determines by which name the value is sent to your script.

In PHP, you can use the superglobal `$_GET`. `$_GET['privacy']` will contain `'0'` or `'1'` depending on the choice made. If the method of the form was `post`, you could use the superglobal `$_POST` instead, or you can use `$_REQUEST`, which contains values from either, so in that case your script doesn't care whether the values were send in the url (get) or in the chunk of invisible post data that is sent along with the request.

Comment: This worked. I had to make a separate form and do this method. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

i have assumes that your form is something as follows.

```
    <form name="sample" action="form_submit.php" method="POST">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="private" name="privacy"   value="0">Private</input>
    <label for="private">Private</label>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="public" name="privacy"   value="1">Public</input>
    <label for="public">Public</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value ="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

you can use the following code inside the action (form_submit.php) to get the selected radio button value.

form_submit.php

```
<?php

$selected_radio = $_POST['privacy'];
print $selected_radio;

?>
```

make sure that you are not duplicating the IDs because they should be unique.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I did as above, and got undefined index errors on a lot of other variables. I have resolved the issue now, GolezTrol's answer worked for me. Thank you for your help though, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

change type to `radio` and donot use the same id for morethan one element id is supposed to be unique

Also when you post the form `type=button` values will not be passed with the form

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" name="privacy"   value="0"/>Private
<input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" name="privacy"   value="1"/>Public
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming its posted on `$_POST['privacy']` should contain either a `1` or a `0`

also dont use an ID twice - they are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `form` and `submit` button.

**HTML page:**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio ">
  <form name="privacyForm" action="action.php" method="post">
    <button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" name="privacy" value="0">Private</button>
    <button type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" name="privacy" value="1">Public</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['privacy']; // should be 0 or 1
?>
```